# equals two objects but it's false

Tags: java

I have been trying to use the `equals()` method and `==` with two `Baby` objects but both gave me `false`.

```
public class Baby {
    String name;

    Baby(String myName) {
        name = myName;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Baby s1 = new Baby("a");
        Baby s2 = new Baby("a");
        System.out.println(s2.equals(s1));
        System.out.println(s1 == s2);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try googling this prior asking....?

Answer (score 7):

Your output is correct: s1 does not in fact equal s2 if you use the  `==` operation since they are distinct separate instances, which is exactly what `==` checks for. Since Baby does not override the equals method, a call to it will default to the `==` operation, returning false. Instead you should have your class *override* the `public boolean equals(Object o)` method and call it when needed.

```
public class Baby {
   String name;

   Baby(String myName) {
      name = myName;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      final int prime = 31;
      int result = 1;
      result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
      return result;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (this == obj)
         return true;
      if (obj == null)
         return false;
      if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
         return false;
      Baby other = (Baby) obj;
      if (name == null) {
         if (other.name != null)
            return false;
      } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
         return false;
      return true;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Baby s1 = new Baby("a");
      Baby s2 = new Baby("a");
      System.out.println(s2.equals(s1));
      System.out.println(s1 == s2);
   }


}
```

Oh, and don't forget to override `hashCode()` as well so you don't have two objects being equal but having two different hashCodes -- not kosher!

Answer (score 2):

`s1 == s2` will only evaluate to `true` if `s1` and `s2` are the *same object*. They are not in your case. They are different objects although the contents may be identical.

The `.equals` method (if implemented correctly; that's your job) compares the contents and therefore, in your case, will return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you override equals, it will tell you that s1 and s2 are indeed distinct objects. They are 2 distinct babies that just happen to have the same name. :)

Answer (score 0):

See this question: [What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion)

which explains the difference between `==` and using the `.equals()` method.

Or this [helpful video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6k4fx3InFA).